# Angualar Interceptor Test client side

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

How Can I test this line // client-side error --> message = error.error.message;

If I use
httpTestingController
.expectOne('/path')
.error(new ErrorEvent('404 Error'), errorResponse);

Always go to the backend error condition.

```
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private httpErrorService: HttpErrorService) {}
 
  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<unknown>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      retry(this.httpErrorService.getHttpRetry()),
      catchError((error) => {
        let message: string;
 
        if (error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
          // client-side error
          message = error.error.message;
        } else {
          // backend error
          message = this.getServerErrorMessage(error);
        }
 
        this.httpErrorService.add(message);
 
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }
```

Thanks!